# How to delete this extra partitions after installing ubuntu again

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I just install ubuntu (again) on this pc, is the second time i have to install the os, because of different reasons. The thing is that i noticed this partitions on the pc. first time i installed ubuntu on this pc there was one of those, now they are 2.
[image]

**ubuntu 20.04.**

**No dualboot**.

**Installed using "Erase disk and install"**

i have ubuntu on an ssd and my files on a second HDD.

**How can i delete that?**

*****If this is a duplicate, please let me know, i could not find a question about this.

** I also have a laptop with dual boot (ubuntu/Windows) and this partitions are not there

[image]

[image]
**They are empty**

[image: It's not Ubuntu server, just the name]

It's not ubuntu server, just the name (just a clarification)

Comment: Edit your question and add a screenshot of the `disks` app. Even better, install `gparted` and add a screenshot of gparted in your question.

Comment: @user68186 is that one ok?

Comment: It's probably not an ESP since this drive has an MBR partition scheme.  OP, you should format the drive **before** installing the OS.  Use Disks from a live session and format the disk choosing the GPT partition scheme. Then you can install Ubuntu

Comment: @Nmath in Windows GPT and UEFI must go together. Linux is more tolerant about mixing and matching UEFI with MBR, though it is not recommended. Since they show up in Nautilus, the ESP flag may not be set. Something is off here.

Comment: Can you give us an idea about what folders files are in these two partitions? When you installed Ubuntu the second time, did you choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" or some other option? Also run this command in a terminal to check if Ubuntu is booted in UEFI or BIOS mode: `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` (this is just one line), and add all these new information to your question.

Comment: @user68186 info and images added

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why these partitions are being created every time you install Ubuntu. To me it looks like the installer creates them for an UEFI install but installs in BIOS mode in the end. This is unusual. I any case, if the partitions are empty, you can delete them using `Gparted`. However, make sure you have backup of your data before doing anything with partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the partitions using the "Disks" app, one month and everything is working correctly so far